# React / Upload file with Axios gives "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Tags: reactjs

Hello

I am trying to upload file with express & react.

Server side, I am using express and express-fileupload

Server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");

const app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post("/upload", (req,res) =>  {
    if (req.files == null) {
        return res.status(400).json({msg : "no files uploaded"});
    }
    const file = req.files.file;
    file.mv(`${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log("no possible mv")
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    res.json({fileName : fileName,filePath:`/uploads/${file.name}`}); 
    });
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server started"));
```

Client side, App.js import my components FileUpload.js :

When I click on my submit form, here is the part of the code which doesn't work :

```js
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    
    const config = {headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
    axios.post("/upload", formData, config)
    .then (res => {
      const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;
      setUploadedFile({ fileName, filePath });
    })
    .catch(error => {console.log(error)})

    }
```

It returns this error :

> Object { message: "Request failed with status code 404", name:
> "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request:
> XMLHttpRequest, response: {…}, stack: "" }

[image: screen copy]

I have also tried await/asynw instead of this promises, but no luck;

console.log of formData and file gives as output :

> FormData {  } : FormDataPrototype { append: append(),
> delete: delete(), get: get(), … }
>
> File { name: "beste bonnard secu.jpg", lastModified: 1659201354916,
> webkitRelativePath: "", size: 169036, type: "image/jpeg" }

Comment: which port do you use for frontend application? Is it the same for frontend and server?

Comment: are you running react and express on different ports? if so, call the absolute url to server instead of just path.

Comment: Server listen on port 5000, and locahost on 3000.

Comment: so, when you write "/upload", you send request to the localhost:3000/upload. You should use localhost:5000/upload instead

Comment: Not if your proxy your react api in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :
In FileUpload in onSubmit method I have added the full url  on this line:

```
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload", formData, {...} )
```

Next terminal and server.js:

1. I have installed cors using `npm install cors --save`
2. plus 2 lines in server.js:

const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())